# Why does VarHandle::getAcquire have so much overhead?

Tags: java, x86, jvm, atomic, varhandle

In C/C++ `stdatomic`s on `x86` provides `release`-`acquire` semantic which is free due to x86 memory model. So the point of using `atomic_load_explicit(&i, memory_order_acquire);` and `atomic_store_explicit(&i, 0, memory_order_release);` is that it does not require any memory barrier instruction to ensure correct `release`-`acquire` semantics on x86.

In Java there's also [`VarHandle::getAcquire`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase%2F9%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2F%2F/java/lang/invoke/VarHandle.html#getAcquire-java.lang.Object...-) and [`VarHandle::setRelease`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase%2F9%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2F%2F/java/lang/invoke/VarHandle.html#setRelease-java.lang.Object...-) which roughly speaking provides the same memory semantic. The problem is when trying to measure `VarHandle::getAcquire` I figured out that it introduces a lot of overhead which essentially destroys the whole point of the optimization. Here is the benchmark:

```
@Warmup(iterations = 5, time = 1, timeUnit = TimeUnit.SECONDS)
@Measurement(iterations = 5, time = 1, timeUnit = TimeUnit.SECONDS)
@Fork(value = 1)
@BenchmarkMode(org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.Mode.AverageTime)
@OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS)
@State(Scope.Benchmark)
public class Benchmarks {

    private int variable = 0;

    private static VarHandle VAR_HANDLE;
    static {
        try {
            MethodHandles.Lookup l = MethodHandles.lookup();
            VAR_HANDLE = l.findVarHandle(Benchmarks.class, "variable", int.class);
        } catch (ReflectiveOperationException e) {
            throw new Error(e);
        }
    }

    @Benchmark
    @BenchmarkMode(Mode.AverageTime)
    public void readAcquire(Blackhole bh) {
        bh.consume(VAR_HANDLE.getAcquire(this));
    }
}
```

so `prof perfasm` shows pretty much lot of noise like:

```
mov     0x20(%r12,%r8,8),%r9d  ;*aaload {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
                           ; - java.lang.invoke.VarHandle::getMethodHandle@10 (line 1979)
                           ; - java.lang.invoke.VarHandleGuards::guard_L_L@50 (line 40)
                           ; - com.test.Benchmarks::readAcquire@5 (line 33)
                           ; - com.test.jmh_generated.Benchmarks_readAcquire_jmhTest::readAcquire_avgt_jmhStub@17 (line 190)
 mov     0x10(%r12,%r9,8),%ecx  ;*getfield type {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
                           ; - java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle::asType@2 (line 839)
                           ; - java.lang.invoke.VarHandleGuards::guard_L_L@59 (line 41)
                           ; - com.test.Benchmarks::readAcquire@5 (line 33)
                           ; - com.test.jmh_generated.Benchmarks_readAcquire_jmhTest::readAcquire_avgt_jmhStub@17 (line 190)
                           ; implicit exception: dispatches to 0x00007f50282ef40c
 cmp     $0xe2d7411d,%ecx  ;   {oop(a &apos;java/lang/invoke/MethodType&apos;{0x0000000716ba08e8} = (Ljava/lang/invoke/VarHandle;Lcom/test/Benchmarks;)Ljava/lang/Object;)}
 je      0x7f50282ef318    ;*if_acmpne {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
                           ; - java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle::asType@5 (line 839)
                           ; - java.lang.invoke.VarHandleGuards::guard_L_L@59 (line 41)
                           ; - com.test.Benchmarks::readAcquire@5 (line 33)
                           ; - com.test.jmh_generated.Benchmarks_readAcquire_jmhTest::readAcquire_avgt_jmhStub@17 (line 190)
 mov     0x18(%r12,%r9,8),%r10d  ;*getfield asTypeCache {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
                           ; - java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle::asTypeCached@1 (line 851)
                           ; - java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle::asType@12 (line 843)
                           ; - java.lang.invoke.VarHandleGuards::guard_L_L@59 (line 41)
                           ; - com.test.Benchmarks::readAcquire@5 (line 33)
                           ; - com.test.jmh_generated.Benchmarks_readAcquire_jmhTest::readAcquire_avgt_jmhStub@17 (line 190)
 mov     0x10(%r12,%r10,8),%r8d  ;*getfield type {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
                           ; - java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle::asTypeCached@11 (line 852)
                           ; - java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle::asType@12 (line 843)
                           ; - java.lang.invoke.VarHandleGuards::guard_L_L@59 (line 41)
                           ; - com.test.Benchmarks::readAcquire@5 (line 33)
                           ; - com.test.jmh_generated.Benchmarks_readAcquire_jmhTest::readAcquire_avgt_jmhStub@17 (line 190)
                           ; implicit exception: dispatches to 0x00007f50282ef428

 cmp     $0xe2d7411d,%r8d  ;   {oop(a &apos;java/lang/invoke/MethodType&apos;{0x0000000716ba08e8} = (Ljava/lang/invoke/VarHandle;Lcom/test/Benchmarks;)Ljava/lang/Object;)}
 jne     0x7f50282ef2e4    ;*if_acmpne {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
                           ; - java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle::asTypeCached@14 (line 852)
                           ; - java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle::asType@12 (line 843)
                           ; - java.lang.invoke.VarHandleGuards::guard_L_L@59 (line 41)
                           ; - com.test.Benchmarks::readAcquire@5 (line 33)
                           ; - com.test.jmh_generated.Benchmarks_readAcquire_jmhTest::readAcquire_avgt_jmhStub@17 (line 190)
 lea     (%r12,%r11,8),%rdx  ;*getstatic VAR_HANDLE {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
                           ; - com.test.Benchmarks::readAcquire@1 (line 33)
                           ; - com.test.jmh_generated.Benchmarks_readAcquire_jmhTest::readAcquire_avgt_jmhStub@17 (line 190)
 lea     (%r12,%r10,8),%rsi  ;*getfield asTypeCache {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
                           ; - java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle::asTypeCached@1 (line 851)
                           ; - java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle::asType@12 (line 843)
                           ; - java.lang.invoke.VarHandleGuards::guard_L_L@59 (line 41)
                           ; - com.test.Benchmarks::readAcquire@5 (line 33)
                           ; - com.test.jmh_generated.Benchmarks_readAcquire_jmhTest::readAcquire_avgt_jmhStub@17 (line 190)
```

or

```
callq   0x7fa21883fd80
  ;*invokevirtual invokeBasic {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=1}
  ;java.lang.invoke.VarHandleGuards::guard_L_L@64 (line 41)
  ;com.test.Benchmarks::readAcquire@5 (line 32)
  ;com.test.jmh_generated.Benchmarks_readAcquire_jmhTest::readAcquire_avgt_jmhStub@17 (line 190)
```

where the `VarHandleGuard::guard__L` looks as

```
static final Object guard__L(VarHandle handle, VarHandle.AccessDescriptor ad) throws Throwable {
    handle.checkExactAccessMode(ad);
    if (handle.isDirect() && handle.vform.methodType_table[ad.type] == ad.symbolicMethodTypeErased) {
        Object r = MethodHandle.linkToStatic(handle, handle.vform.getMemberName(ad.mode));
        return ad.returnType.cast(r);
    } else {
        MethodHandle mh = handle.getMethodHandle(ad.mode);
        return mh.asType(ad.symbolicMethodTypeInvoker).invokeBasic(handle.asDirect());
    }
}
```

which seems to be called implicitly on any `VarHandle` invocation.

---

In Java, `volatile` provides sequential-consistency guarantees, and essentially reading a `volatile` variable does not require extra memory barrier on x86 (unlike other ISAs), but writing to a `volatile` variable usually compiles to an extra `lock addl $0x0, (%rsp)` inserted after memory write instruction.  (C++ compilers use `xchg` instead of `mov` for `seq_cst` stores, instead of a separate `mfence` or `lock`ed instruction.  Slightly cheaper, but the full barrier is the main cost.)

Why does `VarHandle::getAcquire` introduce so much noise and is it possible to use it instead of `volatile` for optimizing for latency?

Comment: The overhead is one `lea` or one `call`?  `lea` is much cheaper than `call` even if the function body was empty, so it matters a lot which happens when, and what's in that function.  One`lea` is also *much* cheaper than a full memory barrier, blocking later loads/stores until the store buffer drains.  If it eventually optimized to just an extra `lea`, that's basically nothing to worry about vs. `volatile`.

Comment: @PeterCordes Actually much more, tho whole instructions set looks too large. Updated.

Comment: @PeterCordes Judging by the assembly output, produced by `JMH` the some `guard__L_L` function is called implicitly on each `VarHandle` invocation making acquire-release implementation pretty much useless (IMO).

Comment: Is that a loop body?  You aren't showing branch targets.  Is it doing some kind of SeqLock thing with the "guard" variable?  Possibly we're just seeing the test function inlined into the benchmark loop, although from the asm comments about a "guard" variable it does look like there's some overhead.

Comment: @PeterCordes The JMH benchmarking framework uses loop under the hood and the “guard” code was inlined in the actual benchmarking method (judging by the output asm). The thing is a simple volatile read shows almost 10 times better latency in the same JMH benchmark and does not have all this guard related noise.

Comment: Latency for what?  Inter-thread latency, like time between a store on one core and a spin-loop seeing it on another core?

Comment: @PeterCordes This is actually CLOCK_MONOTONIC samples taken before and after the benchmark invocation.

Comment: Before / after a whole benchmark repeat-loop?  Doesn't JMH adjust iteration count so you wouldn't be benchmarking a fixed amount of work?  Or do you mean you timed one call to  `readAcquire(Blackhole bh)` instead of using JMH?  How did you warm up the JVM to make sure you were timing an optimized run?

Comment: Are you sure one second is sufficient per warmup iteration?

Comment: Related: [Unexpected VarHandle performance (4X slower than alternatives)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58863128). Probably an exact duplicate; you're feeding the blackhole with the `getAcquire` return value directly, which apparently is a boxed `int`, not just a raw `int`.

Comment: BTW, it seems insane to me that this VarHandle stuff needs to put a variable name in a string literal to get a wrapper able to do atomic operations on it; C++20 `std::atomic_reference()` just takes a reference like a normal C++ class, and you're intended to construct one on the fly every time you want to do an atomic op on a plain object.  IDK if the actual VarHandle object optimizes away, but it seems very clunky and inconvenient, and like you'd expect it to have a lot of overhead if it's not handled very specially by the JIT.  (But hopefully it is, I think that's the point).

Comment: @PeterCordes the string is only needed for obtaining/looking up the `VarHandle`, not for accessing it. I think there are other possibilities but these woukd require custom bytecode I think. After all, Java has no syntax for getting a real reference to a variable. And yes, AFAIK, the JIT should be able to optimize `VarHandle` accesses, especially with `static final VarHandle`s.

Comment: @PeterCordes Nice catch, just checked the benchmark and the JIT compiled code is not comparable to a simple load instruction (including additional read of the `VAR_HANDLE` itself)

Comment: @dan1st _the string is only needed for obtaining/looking up the VarHandle, not for accessing it_ right, and I expected it to be optimised away mostly, but explicitly casted it to reference instead of primitive. It introduced the significant noise.

Comment: @dan1st: So unlike C++ `std::atomic_ref`, you shouldn't just construct a `VarHandle` on the fly because that part actually might be expensive?  Should we expect a `static final VarHandle` to fully optimize away so it takes no space in the object and doesn't introduce an extra level of indirection, or would a class with an `int` member and a varhandle for doing atomic accesses on it also end up storing a pointer to an `int` in the JITed asm, along with the actual `int`?

Comment: @dan1st: I'd have expected new support for non-seq_cst atomics in Java to involve new bytecode.  But I'm guessing this design requiring reflection is designed to avoid that.  (Maybe wouldn't have been easily possible without some new syntax or keyword as well, which is more undesirable for backwards compatibility with code that might have used any given keyword as a variable.  And unlike C, they're not going to pick names like `_Atomic` for new features.)

Comment: @PeterCordes It usually constructed as a static final variable on the class initialization step. It then roughly speaking contains memory offset within the object a given `VAR_HANDLE` is applied to. In C `_Atomic` qualifier can be implicitly added to a pointer type when passing a parameter to `atomic_store`/`atomic_load`

Comment: @SomeName: It's UB to pass a pointer to a plain `int` to `atomic_load` or `store`.  ISO C doesn't have any equivalent to C++20 `std::atomic_ref`.  (GNU C has `__atomic_load` / `__atomic_store_n` etc. that do atomic ops on plain vars.)  In practice (https://godbolt.org/z/Yzqcn4Whh), clang treats it as a compile-time error without a cast, but GCC surprisingly allows implicit conversion without even a warning from `-Wall -Wextra`.  Some kinds of errors require a diagnostic so now I'm curious if both compiler behaviours are valid.  If it's just UB, then anything goes.

Comment: @PeterCordes Yes, looking up a `VarHandle` is (relatively) expensive. The advantage of `VarHandle`s is that _accessing_ them is cheap. A `static final VarHandle` isn't completely optimized away as I know since it still needs to store the `VarHandle` variable (e.g. you could access the `VarHandle` variable by reflection or similar) but the accesses to it should be optimized as much as possible (of course: measure, don't guess and also don't trust me). Also AFAIK, the amount of available bytecode instructions is limited so they don't add new bytecode instructions unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: Also, there are discussions about adding a `non-atomic` keyword (vs a `LooslyConsistentValue` interface, see the Valhalla mailing lists for details) so they are ok with adding "features" containing `atomic` in their name (if it makes sense ofc). However, they don't want to add bytecode instructions if possible.

Comment: @PeterCordes Indeed, _for any q-qualified_ does not mean __Atomic_ qualifier unless it's explicitly mentioned.

Comment: It looks like you forgot to declare `VAR_HANDLE` as `final`.

Comment: As @PeterCordes already pointed out, my guess is that your problem is caused by not explicitly casting to an int.

If you would do this: "public int readAcquire() { return (int)VAR_HANDLE.getAcquire(this);} then the performance of the getAcquire should be very good. Without the int cast, the signature polymorphism can't do its magic. If you would run with a -prof gc, then in your current code you should see a high allocation rate and after the int cast, the allocation rate should be zero.

Comment: Perhaps there will not be a high allocation rate because always 0 is returned and I guess the JVM will optimize for that. But if you would set the initial value to a few million, then you should see a high allocation rate.

Comment: @pveentjer Shouldn't the allocation rate be low from the start on because of Java using the same `Integer` for (close to 0) ints?

Comment: Yes. That is why I added my second comment. If he would set the value to a higher number than 0 (e.g. a million) he should see a high rate of litter with his current code.